# How do I set up "var count" so that it is initialized the first time and then incremented?

Tags: javascript

I tried [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8xPDE/):

```
var count;

function testCount ()
{
  if (count)
  {
    alert("count is: " + count);
    count++;
  }    
  else
  {    
    alert("count is: " + count);
    var count = 0;
  }
};

testCount();
```

but it always gives "undefined" and the value of count is not updated when I run it again in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that nobody has shown the simple `testCount()` implementation.  Just initialize it upon declaration and then just use it in your function:

```
var count = 0;

function testCount ()
{
    alert("count is: " + count);
    count++;
}

testCount();
```

Comment: this gives "count is: 0" when I run it again in jsfiddle. Is that because the way jsfiddle is set up? http://jsfiddle.net/8xPDE/2/

Comment: That is correct.  That's how `testCount()` is implemented in your first post.  It displays the value of `count` before it is incremented.  Call it a second time and it will show count of `1`: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/EusVJ/.  If you want to display the value after it's incremented, then just put the `count++` before the `alert`.

Answer (score 2):

Just initialize it at declaration:

```
var count = 0;
```

And don't declare a second `count` within your `else`. That's a completely separate variable.

The problem in your code is that the `count` within the `else` block is different from the one you have declared in the global scope. This happens because you are defining a new variable with the same name by using `var count = 0;` within the `else` clause which will not be referring to the `count` variable declared outside of the function.

If you remove the `var` withing your `else`, things will work as you expect:

```
var count;

function testCount ()
{
  if (count)
  {
    alert("count is: " + count);
    count++;
  }    
  else
  {    
    alert("count is: " + count);
    count = 0;
  }
};

testCount();
```

However, if you call `testCount` again, the `if` will evaluate to `false`, as `0` is a "falsey" value in Javascript.

Comment: There's a small problem with this piece of code. `count` will always be 0, regardless of how many times you call `testCount()`

Comment: @NullUserExceptionఠ_ఠ - true enough, seeing as `0` is a `falsey` value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you cant just

```
var count = 0;
```

You can detect its lack of an assigned value with;

```
if (typeof count === 'undefined')
   count = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a problem of variable scope.

When outside a function, you define a variable, this variable is global. In other word, when you do :

```
var count;
```

You declare count, and you can use it everywhere.

Now, in a function, when you declare count as below :

```
function testCount ()
{
    ...
    alert("count is: " + count);
    var count = 0;
    ...
};
```

you declare a new variable whose scope is in the function, and initialize it with 0. However, what you want is to change the global variable value. So, just do that :

```
function testCount ()
{
    ...
    alert("count is: " + count);
    count = 0;
    ...
};
```

Note that I have removed the **var** keyword.

Now, to simplify the whole program, I suggest you that :

```
var count = 0;

function testCount ()
{
    alert("count is: " + count);
    count++;
};
```

- the initialization is made with the declaration
- so you do not need to worry about the initialization inside testCount
- your code is lighter