# How do I make a count variable persistent across sessions?

Tags: javascript, session

I have a static page `/story` that has a button that says "make your choice" which is handled by `/choice`. In `/choice` I have this script in the header

```
var count = 0;

function writeToStorage()
{ 
  var user = "user" + count;
  count++;
  localStorage.setItem("chooser", user);

  document.getElementById("form_chooser").value = user;  
};
```

So, every time `/choice` is called by `/story` "count" is reset to zero. How do I make "count" persistent so that each time `/choice` is called the current value is used?

I asked a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106644/how-do-i-set-up-var-count-so-that-it-is-initialized-the-first-time-and-then-in) for this, but I think it was not clear what I wanted to do and the answers concentrated on the function `writeToStorage()`. It is true that if I call `writeToStorage` several times in one session

```
writeToStorage();
writeToStorage();
writeToStorage();
```

"count" is incremented but as soon as `/choice` is run the count is reset to zero. I would like "count" to persist. Thanks.

Comment: well count is 0 when the page and script get loaded, can't you use localStorage to set the user count as well?

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand how localStorage works. I thought that if `user1` clicks the button to fire `writeToStorage()` the data is written to `user1`'s machine. When `user2` clicks the button to fire `writeToStorage` how do I know the count that was written in `user1`'s machine? As I said, I may be totally misunderstanding how localStorage works.

Comment: the only thing that gets persisted in local storage is what you tell it directly via localStorage.setItem...it doesn't persist all the javascript variables that are in memory.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand, can you answer with some code? If I set the count in localStorage with user1 how do I get the count with user2?

Comment: Storage scope is only that of the user's machine. You cannot find out user1's value from user2's machine without a server side script.

Comment: @TimJoyce; ok then how can I give each new user a new user name in the form `user+count` or user1, user2, user3 and so on. I am studying your answer too but I think you also check the localStorage for count. Thanks

Comment: That will depend on what kind of server you are on. We will need to determine what server language you should use, The easiest way to do it might be to just write to a text file on the server since (no offense) but it doesn't sound like you are familiar with server side scripts.

Comment: @TimJoyce; I am working with Google App Engine with Python. I created the handler `/counthandler` in the app that increments "count". I used XMLHttpRequest before but I am not sure how it will work in this case. So if you could sketch that for me that would be helpful. For instance, I used xhr to send formData, but in this case I need to get the count number from the app. Thanks

Comment: @Zeynel I think StackOverflow would appreciate it if you deem this question closed and open a new one, please. I think ultimately your question was "how do I get local storage key/values to reference each other on multiple user's machines with javascript". I'm pretty sure the community consensus will be that you can't. So now you need to retag  and reword your question.

Answer (score 5):

Smth along these lines:

```
    var count = localStorage.getItem("count") || 0;

function writeToStorage() {

    count++;
    localStorage.setItem("count", count);
    document.getElementById("form_chooser").value = "user" + count;

};
```

So, first line gets the current local storage count or 0 if it's undefined ( if the count was never stored, the user camed for the first time to you're page ) , then you increment the count and save it . Then write the current count in the element .

Comment: ok, but I thought that when you write to localStorage you save to the user's machine? Is this correct? If so how do I know the count in different users machine?

Comment: LocalStorage is saved inside the browser, sort of like a cookie. You'll be able to know the count of the same user who wisits the site on different browsers/machines if you save it in you're application database so the count will sit on the server side .

Comment: I am sorry, I guess the question was not clear. My problem is to give each new user a user name in the form user1, user2, user3 and so on. So "count" is the number that I append to "user", not how many times the user visits. Thanks.

Comment: Oki then you need to store that in you're database not on localstorage, so it will go smth like this: each time a new user visits if he doesn't have the username stored on localstorage then you make an ajax request to get the count from the server and then save it in the user localstorage so that the next time he visits you whont increment .

Answer (score 1):

```
function storage (){
    var canStore = true;
    if (typeof(localStorage) == 'undefined' ) {
        canStore = false;
    }
    return canStore;
};

function getStorageVal(key){
    if (storage()) {
        return localStorage.getItem(key);   
    }
}

var count = getStorageVal('chooser');
count++;
var user = "user" + count;

localStorage.setItem("chooser", user);

document.getElementById("form_chooser").value = user;
```