# How do I get a count variable from python handler to javascript function?

Tags: javascript, python, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to issue a user name to each new user in the form user1, user2, user3 and so on.

As the result of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8123032/how-do-i-make-a-count-variable-persistent-across-sessions), now I understand that I need to keep track of count in the app and not in the browser. So I created `/counthandler` (I am working with Google App Engine Python):

```
class CountHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        count = count + 1
```

In `/choice`, I have this script:

```
function writeToStorage()
{ 
  var user = "user" + count;
  localStorage.setItem("chooser", user);

  document.getElementById("form_chooser").value = user;  
};
```

How do I get "count" from `/counthandler` to `writeToStorage`? I understand I need to use HMLHttpRequest, but not sure how. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

In response to jfriend00's comment, I add more specific question about ajax call:

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8086/counthandler", true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){ 
      console.log("request 200-OK");
    }
    else {
      console.log("connection error");
    }
  };
  //I am not sure what to put in send()?
  xhr.send();
```

**UPDATE 2**

In response to jfriend00's comment, and reference supplied, I changed the call to GET; but not sure what happens after this:

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8086/counthandler", true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){ 
      console.log("request 200-OK");
    }
    else {
      console.log("connection error");
    }
  };
  //changed this to "null". this now opens the connection.
  //what do I do after this?
  xhr.send(null);
```

**Update to answer jfriend00's updated answer:**

Thanks for the detailed explanation. Now I understand. But there is still something that I am missing. It is easy to get the value of count:

```
query = Count.all()
query.get()
count = e.count
logging.info("count = %s" % count)
# gives count = 12
```

Now you are saying that, assign the value of python variable "count" which is 12 to the js variable "count" with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 12;
</script>
```

What I don't understand is what happens next time when the count = 13?

It seems to me that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = count;
</script>
```

will not work. Correct? What am I missing?

Thanks again.

---

**Update to try the second option in jfriend00's answer. It seems that I need to include a success function to get the "count" variable sent by `/counthandler`:**

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        {
            //get "count" sent by /counthandler?
            //var count = count;
        }
    };
    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8086/counthandler", true);
    xhr.send(null);
```

But I still I don't understand how `/counthandler` sends the "count" and how I can can get it inside the success function.

Comment: Why do you want to use localStorage at all? Your original justification, ie to store a global counter, is no longer relevant, so why still use it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman; I want to write the user name that I give to the user, for instance, "user1" so that I can track the comments made by user1. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are keeping track of the variable server-side and you want to put it in your web page, then you just output a javascript variable to the web page with the value of count.  Thus if your server has a count of 12, then you just output this to the web page from your web server app:

```
var count = 12;
```

Any client-side javascript code can then have access to the value of that count variable.  If you want to modify the count variable from the client-side web page, you will have to make a server request in order to modify it on the server (a Post or Get) typically done with a form post or an ajax call.

---

There are two ways you could approach this problem:

### Option 1:

You've said you have the value of count on your server.  It's stored on your server somewhere.  It's not in /counthandler or /choice - those are just scripts that run on your server.  So, if you want the count value in the /choice web page, then you go modify the /choice python script and you obtain the value of count in that script and you insert it into the web page the same way you would put anything else in the web page from a python script (exactly how you do that depends upon what python environment you are using), but if you are already creating web pages from python scripts you must already be doing this.  Then, in an appropriate place in that web page, you put this piece of javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 12;
</script>
```

You do NOT get the value from /counthandler and put it in /count from the server.  Within the /count script, you fetch the value of count and put it into that web page.

### Option2:

In the /choice web page, you make an ajax request to some server page (perhaps /counthandler) to fetch the current count.  The success handler from that ajax call will have the desired count value and you can then whatever you want with it in the web page.

As for writing it to localstorage, we still have no idea why you're evening try to do that since you seem to be storing it on the server already.  localstorage is browser-specific storage that only works in that specific browser and can be cleared at any time by the user.

Comment: I think I need help with the ajax call. I am not sure what I will be sending with `xhr.send();` and how the app will send the "count" and what the callback function be. Any more specific help with these would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Explaining ajax to you is beyond the scope of a comment here.  There are hundreds of thousands of web pages that document how to make ajax calls.  You should start there and, if you try something and get stuck as a specific question about your code.  If you can use a library like jQuery or YUI, cross-browser ajax calls are a lot simpler.

Comment: I updated the question with a more specific question. I am not sure what information I need to send to `/counthandler` in `xhr.send()`. Thanks.

Comment: Here's one reference for you to look at: http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php.  Google is your friend here.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the call to GET as the page you referenced says it is simpler, and I changed `xhr.send();` to `xhr.send(null);` As the page says this now opens the connection. What do I have to do next? I updated the question with these changes.

Comment: I'm surprised you can't just read how this works.  When using `get`, you put the parameters of your request in the URL (see how it's done in that example): `http://localhost:8086/counthandler?newCount=32` and your server gets the parameters from the URL or that is done for you already depending upon what server environment you are using.

Comment: I am sorry, I am confused about the order. I am trying to get `/counthandler` to send the count number back to `writeToStorage()`. Where does `http://localhost:8086/counthandler?newCount=32` go?

Comment: You are very, very confused.  Please read my answer again.  You DO NOT send the count from `/counthandler` to `writeToStorage()` and that just doesn't make sense.  You can use the server to insert the count into the web page (just like my answer describes) OR you can use ajax to send a new count from the web page to the server.  There are two options here.  You communicate the count from server to client (by embedding it in a web page like in my answer above) or you communicate the count from client to server with ajax or a form post or a URL request.

Comment: Once the count is on the client, you can write it to local storage if you want to (thought I'm not sure why).

Comment: I don't understand how I "output a javascript variable to the web page with the value of count." "count" is a python variable in `/counthandler`. I need to pass this variable to `writeToStorage()` in `/choice`. Can you give me a clue about where `var count = count` should go? And I don't want to write "count" to `localStorage`. Thanks again.

Comment: I added more explanation to my answer.  I'll be signing out now for awhile.

Comment: Thanks. When you get a chance, I updated my question in response.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4990/discussion-between-jfriend00-and-zeynel)

Answer (score 1):

I must say, you're going about this completely the wrong way and thus making things much harder for yourself than they need to be.

The proper place for storing things like usernames is not in Javascript local storage, but in a cookie. No AJAX required, just server-side code.

You don't say what server-side framework you're using, but assuming it's Django, you would just do `response.set_cookie('username', username)` - although if you are using Django, I can't imagine why you wouldn't be using the built-in authentication framework.

Comment: I don't know how to work with cookies, although this would be a good time to learn. I am using GAE Python without Django. I want to make a user coming first time to the site as easy as possible to write a first comment without choosing a user name or entering an email or password. When the user clicks the submit button I assign a user name. The problem is with the persistent counter, not saving the user name. I need the counter to assign user names in the form "user+counter" or, user1, user2, user3 and so on. Thanks and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: But that's my point, all this happens server-side. No need for AJAX or localStorage.

Comment: Ok, say I created and assigned first user name server side. When a new user clicks the submit button for a first comment, `/counthandler` creates the new "user+count" and saves it to datastore. Next time the same user visits the site how do I know his user name? What am I missing?